# What height for towel bar blocking?

Tags: bathroom

As an Architect, it appears the solution is to add 2x6 blocking in the wall adjacent to shower.  Just curious at what height to add the blocking. Centered at 44" unless noted otherwise.

Comment: Towel racks you can cheat and use drywall anchors for one end.  Something like a support bar you would want blocking or studs.

Comment: @crip659 I disagree. I would always treat a towel bar, if in reach of a toilet, tub or shower, as "might get used by a grab bar sometime" and therefore want it anchored into solid wood at both ends.

Comment: Don’t forget to adjust for top of wainscoting, which might end up at about that dimension too.

Comment: Instead of 2x6 how about 3/4 inch ply, a band 2 feet tall from 4 to 6 feet high wherever need?  So you have a 2 ft margin of error instead of 6".

Comment: @J... Those anchors can hold 100lbs of vertical static charge. That's fine for a shelf that you just look at. Towel racks are often manipulated, and when you are in the shower trying to grab your towel, the anchor may experience pullout stress and/or cantilever action, rather than just vertical charge. In that case, the 100lbs means nothing.

Comment: This is entirely a matter of opinion and local conditions (nearby fixtures, towel size, occupant height, etc.) There is no standard. VTC.

Comment: @J..., only under perfect conditions do such anchors hold such loads, and that doesn't consider daily impact damage, which is cumulative. Eventually drywall fails in such cases. You should really throw such wisdom out the window. At least reduce your values by 75%.

Comment: Drywall anchors work perfectly on paper and there's no reason they shouldn't do exactly what you expect them to.  Except that they don't.  Drywall anchors are a last ditch, hail mary solution and you are condemning future owners/users to annoying band-aid fixes while they desperately attempt to avoid expensive drywall repairs.  I have used them all and they are all crap.

Comment: @J..., I don't tear towel bars off walls. What I do, however, is notice that they usually end up wiggly after a while, and if a person wants to remove them to paint, for example, they never quite end up as snug as they originally did. Sure, they work in some cases. It's far from a sure win.

Comment: You're asking where to install the blocking, then answer yourself. Self-answered questions are perfectly acceptable here, but the answer should go down there in the box labeled "Answer", not up here in the box labeled "Question".

Comment: @J... A toggle bolt won't break if you pull it with 100lbs force. The drywall will. Guaranteed. Would you hang two cement bags from the ceiling with such an anchor?

Comment: @J... The bathroom is a common room for falls, someone who's falling is going to grab on to the towel rack instinctively (ask me how I know). If you ever have a child in the house, they will certainly grab it and try to play on it. Etc. There's just not really a down side to making your towel rack overly sturdy.

Answer (score 8):

I'll post this as an answer, but it's really a frame challenge.

As manassehkatz-Moving to Codidact correctly notes, many people just reach for towel bars and use them as grab bars. I like doing that too. So when I installed my last set, I used grab bars in place of towel bars, making sure each end was fastened with actual screws into studs:

[image]

*(image from Google Images)*

That last installation (four different bars in a master bath) was in 2008. Each is still secure and firmly attached. It's a pleasure to hold such a large and confidence-inspiring bar.

Comment: Despite the poor title, the only question posed is about blocking height. This doesn't address that.

Answer (score 5):

For a better in depth discussion of framing for grab bars you should read chapter 6 of the fair housing design guide.  Typically you specify blocking at the heights that would be required to support grab bars around toilets, showers, etc.  Installing the blocking at the framing stage allows these aids to be installed in the future with little effort and the cost to install the blocking when framing is fairly minimal.

https://www.huduser.gov/portal/publications/PDF/FAIRHOUSING/fairfull.pdf

Comment: What's your answer to the height question? Links to other sites don't qualify as answers on SE. You should copy the relevant information here.

Comment: The question was about towel racks, not grab bars. The linked document does not mention "towel" anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

Blocking is very inexpensive.

When I have put in blocking for eventual towel rods, etc., I have put in multiple 2x6, stacked, so that the end user has very broad leeway as to where to install it.

Then I put a tape up against the wall and stand back and take photos so that, in the future, you can see exactly what height from the floor the blocking begins and ends.

Don't create future pain for people with just a single 2x6 block - give them 12 inches to work with.